# How can I write Dockerfile? I wanna execute some of my .py files in docker container

Tags: python, dockerfile

How can I write Dockerfile?

I wanna execute some of my .py files in docker container using Dockerfile.

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest

LABEL maintainer ~~

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD python my_py.py
```

And I commanded

> `docker build -t myapp .`
>
> > Successfully tagged myapp:latest
>
> `docker run -it myapp`
>
> > `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xeb' in file my_py.py on line 15. ~~~`
> >
> >   So, I added it (in top of the file)>>>   `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
> > And I rebuilt, retried
>
> `docker run -it myapp`
>
> > `ImportError: No module named requests`

**When I tried to execute my_py.py in this container, this is worked well.**

What is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mentioning the full python binary path.

```
CMD /opt/conda/bin/python my_py.py
```

Or a better way would be to add ENV. In order to make new software easier to run, you can use ENV to update the PATH environment variable for the software your container installs. For example,

```
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
```

will ensure that `CMD python my_py.py` just works.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest

LABEL maintainer ~~

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

CMD python my_py.py
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to install `requests` module using pip

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest

LABEL maintainer ~~

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m pip install requests

#or RUN pip install requests

CMD python my_py.py
```

try this out.